# Does any uncertainty relation exist for interfering measurements (ie. for 2 subsequent measurements of 2 incompatible observables on the same system)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

To test the usual [Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) bound, we follow the methods delineated in the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169730/) by Timaeus. This method talks about non-interfering measurements. For two incompatible (or compatible) observables, A and B, we **do not** measure both on the same system.

However, if it turns out that for some experiments, it is necessary to make two subsequent measurements of two non-commuting operators, A and B, on the same system, then the Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relation cannot be used anymore. For those kinds of experiments, does there exist a separate, rigorous uncertainty relation like the Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relation?

Comment: Do the observables have continuous spectra, like the traditional position or momentum observables? Then $\sigma_A$ is still nonzero even after $A$ is measured, because it can't be measured with infinite resolution, so the RS uncertainty relation can still be used to get $\sigma_B$. (Use the Heisenberg picture so that all unitary time-evolution is already built into the operators $A$ and $B$.) Or do the observables have discrete spectra? In that case you're right: the RS uncertainty relation is useless because $\sigma_A=0$ after a perfect measurement of $A$, so it says nothing about $\sigma_B$.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Why can the RS uncertainty relation still be used in the case when $\sigma_A$ is non-zero? The derivation relies on the fact that the expectation values of the operators that go into $\sigma_{A,B}$ are evaluated over the same state. If one first measures $A$ and then $B$ then the expectation values that go into $\sigma_B$ will be evaluated over a different state than the state over which the expectation values that go into $\sigma_A$ are evaluated, right?

Comment: I am imagining an ensemble, in which all states are prepared in state $\psi$. On each copy, I first measure A at time t. At the next instant t+dt, suppose I measure B, on all the copies (which had already collapsed into some eigenstate of A, with known probabilities, due to the first measurement). I this sort of experiment will involve some other uncertainty principle.

Comment: Does the "error-disturbance (uncertainty) relations" in Martin's answer have anything to do with my question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169730/uncertainty-principle-and-measurement?noredirect=1&lq=1 Also section 6.1 in the article https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-uncertainty/

Comment: @DvijD.C. You're right that the RS relation evaluates both $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ in a single state. The idea behind my comment is that after we measure $A$ and know the outcome, we should use that post-measurement state to evaluate $\sigma_A$, $\sigma_B$, and the right-hand side of the RS realtion. As long as the post-measurement state is not an eigenstate of $A$, both $\sigma_A$ and (generally) the right-hand side of the RS relation will be non-zero, so we can use it to get $\sigma_B$ in that post-measurement state.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Regarding your 1st reply: As long as the $A$-measurement isn't perfect, so that $\sigma_A$ is still non-zero, we should still be able to use the RS relation with a suitable ensemble average over the $A$-measurement outcomes. I suppose that's a bit of a hack, though: the fact that it becomes useless for perfect measurements is probably a sign that it's not the most natural approach for *any* measurements. Regarding your 2nd reply: I don't know, but it looks promising!

Comment: There appears to be a nice paper by Distler and Paban on this topic: [Uncertainties in Successive Measurements](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4169). I am not sure how my answer relates to their results, but the paper looks interesting. I will try to study the paper in more detail when I get the time and append my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Thank you for the efforts you have put in :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a prior familiarity with this problem, but I found it quite interesting so I tried to scrabble around a bit and it looks like one can get a marginally non-ugly relation for the uncertainties of the kind that OP is interested in.

---

Let's consider the density matrix $\tilde{\rho}$ of the system after the measurement of the first operator $A$. It is easy to see that

\begin{align}
\tilde\rho&=\sum_a \mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a
\end{align}

where $\rho=\vert\psi\rangle\langle\psi\vert$ is the initial (pure state) density matrix of the system, and $\mathbb{P}_a$ are the projection operators corresponding to the eigensubspaces of the operator $A$.

The measurement of the operator $A$, performed over $\rho$, has the well-known uncertainty given by

\begin{align}
\sigma_A^2 =\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]
\end{align}

For a more detailed calculation leading to the above expression, starting from the familiar state-vector formulation, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554471/extension-of-uncertainty-principle-to-mixed-states/554474#554474) of mine which deals with the usual RS uncertainty principle in the density matrix formulation. In order to keep the following discussion self-contained, I will freely copy relevant parts of the linked answer.

Similarly, the measurement of the operator $B$, performed over $\tilde{\rho}$ would carry an uncertainty given by

\begin{align}
\sigma_B^2 &=\mathrm{Tr}\big[\tilde\rho\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\big]\\
\end{align}

Notice that we are adopting a compact notation for the expectation value which can lead to confusion if one loses sight of the fact that $\langle B\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\tilde{\rho}B)$ whreas $\langle A\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho A)$.

Thus, we can write
\begin{align}
\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2&=\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\tilde\rho\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\big]\\
\mathrm{(linearity\ of\ trace)}&=\sum_a\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\big]\\
\mathrm{(cyclic\ property\ of\ trace)}&=\sum_a\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\mathbb{P}_a\big]\\
\mathrm{(idempotent\ nature\ of\ }\mathbb{P}_a\mathrm{)}&=\sum_a\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\mathbb{P}^2_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\mathbb{P}^2_a\big]\\
\end{align}
Now, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities hold true for all inner products, and [it can be shown that for Hermitian operators $X$ and $Y$, it takes the following form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820260/trace-cauchy-schwarz-inequality)

\begin{align}
\big|\text{Tr}\big(SX Y\big)\big|^2 \leq \text{Tr}\big(SX^2\big)\text{Tr}\big(SY^2\big)
\end{align}
where $S$ is a semi-positive definite matrix. Since $\rho$ is a semi-positive definite matrix and $A-\langle A\rangle$, and $\mathbb{P}_a(B-\langle B\rangle)\mathbb{P}_a$ are Hermitian operators, an application of this inequality yields
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\mathbb{P}^2_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\mathbb{P}^2_a\big] &\geq \Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big]\ \Big\vert^2\\
\implies \sum_a\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)^2\big]\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\mathbb{P}^2_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)^2\mathbb{P}^2_a\big] &\geq \sum_a\Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big]\ \Big\vert^2 \\
\implies \sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2&\geq \sum_a\Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big]\ \Big\vert^2\\
\end{align}
We take a pause from our mainline calculation and manipulate the terms appearing on the RHS in the expression above. Using the benefit of the hindsight, we write
\begin{align}
\zeta_a&\equiv\mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A-\langle A\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big(B-\langle B\rangle\big)\mathbb{P}_a\big] \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}\big[\rho\big(A\mathbb{P}_aB\mathbb{P}_a-A\mathbb{P}_a\langle B \rangle \mathbb{P}_a - \langle A\rangle\mathbb{P}_aB\mathbb{P}_a+\langle A\rangle \mathbb{P}_a\langle B\rangle\mathbb{P}_a\big)\big]\\
&=\mathrm{Tr}\big[\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a\big(AB-\langle A\rangle B- \langle B\rangle A + \langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle \big)\big]\\
\implies \zeta_a^* &= \mathrm{Tr}\big[\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a\big(BA-\langle A\rangle B - \langle B\rangle A + \langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle \big)\big]\\
\implies \mathrm{Im}(\zeta_a) &= \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Tr}\big(\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a[A,B]\big) 
\end{align}
where we used the linearity of the trace, the cyclic property of the trace, and ${\mathrm{Tr}(A)^*}=\mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger)$ along with the Hermiticity of the operators and the fact that $\mathbb{P}_a$ commutes with $A$ whenever necessary.

We now invoke the argument that modulus square of a complex number should be bigger than or equal to the square of its imaginary part. We can thus write
\begin{align}
\sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2&\geq \sum_a \Big\vert\ \mathrm{Im}(\zeta_a)\ \Big\vert^2 \\
\implies \sigma_A^2\sigma_B^2&\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_a \Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big(\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a[A,B]\big)\ \Big\vert^2
\end{align}
Or, in other words,
$$\boxed{\sigma_A\sigma_B\geq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sum_a \Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big(\mathbb{P}_a\rho\mathbb{P}_a[A,B]\big)\ \Big\vert^2}}$$
Notice that the traditional RS uncertainty relation in the form of density matrix reads
\begin{align}
\sigma_A\sigma_B&\geq\frac{1}{2} \Big\vert\ \mathrm{Tr}\big(\rho[A,B]\big)\ \Big\vert
\end{align}

Comment: The upshot of your answer is that subsequent measurements on the same system lead to a separate uncertainty inequality than the RS uncertainty inequality. Am I right?